# Implement multiple middleware for authentication and Multer in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multer

I have a form sent from an Angular front-end to a nodeJS server.

This form can contain input file (not mandatory) and other text fields.

So i'm using FormData for the multipart encoding.

Here is the code from my Angular service :

```
const formDataGenerated = generateFormDataFromForm(form);
formDataGenerated.append('id', this.tokenStorage.getUser().id);
if (file !== null) {
  formDataGenerated.append('file', file);
  formDataGenerated.set('riddleFile', file.name);
}
  
return this.http.post(QUEST_API + 'create', formDataGenerated)
  .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      return res;
    })
  );
```

i'm using this route in nodeJS: `router.post('/create', [auth, multer], questCtrl.create);`

The second middleware 'multer' is working fine

```
const util = require("util");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require('path')

const pathFile = path.resolve('./resources/assets/uploads/')


let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, pathFile);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});


let uploadFile = multer({
  storage: storage,
}).single("file");


let uploadFileMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFile);


module.exports = uploadFileMiddleware;
```

And when i'm in my questController i can get all the form values like this :

```
  const formValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

At this point, my file is correctly uploaded and i can get all the needed data from the submited form

But now, i want to add another middleware that will allow me to authenticate the user using JwtToken.
In this code i need to access `req.body.id` that is submitted in FormData

But now, due to the multipart enconding i can't access this property so easily.

So my question is, how to implement my '**auth**' middleware and after the user is authorized, continue on my multer middleware and controller (as it's currently working)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the request in Express falls through middleware until it is not broken by `res.send()`. The "jump" to next middleware is secured with `next()` function, that is passed to the middleware as third argument.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
     if (req.body.password === 'mypassword') {
             req.myAuthentication = true // append whatever props to req
     console.log('I have authenticated the user!')
     next() <-- sends request to the next middleware
})

app.get('/authenticated', (req, res, next) => {
     if (req.myAuthentication) {  // use your property in next middleware
        res.sendFile('authenticated.html')
     }
     res.status(401)
     next() <-- no effect, res.send/res.status finishes the middleware fn
```